# How to Reduce the Overfitting of a Linear Classifier

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, image-segmentation, machine-learning, classification

I am working in linear classification such as $$y=ax+b.$$ where $x=[x_1...x_n]$. But the method has weakness that is overfitting problem. Could you suggest to me one method or one way to reduce overfitting problem in linear classification (don't consisder other method ex SVM).

Comment: Use a subset of {x1, ..., xn}? regularization?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: We can use both of them. And If we use regularization term, we must some prior information,right?Could you show both of them

Comment: How many classes are you separating the data into? If it's just two, I don't think there could be such thing as overfitting. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @John, Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there are 3 main approaches:

1. Objective Function
   Add some regularization to the objective function. If the parameters of the model are given by the vector $ \boldsymbol{w} $ then you may add $ \lambda {\left\| \boldsymbol{w} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ or / and $ \lambda {\left\| \boldsymbol{w} \right\|}_{1} $ as a regularization terms.
2. Features
   Reduce the number of features by a proper selection of them. Since your model is linear, correlation can be a good place to start with.
3. Ensemble
   You may create an ensemble of classifiers. Each can be trained on a subset of the data / features. Then merge them by various policies (Majority, Probability, etc...).